# Capture video by UIImagepickerController record video with custom overlay

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app, which has the facility to record video. I know that the usual practice is to record video using `UIImagePickerController`, but I require to record video with a custom overlay on the top of `UIImagePickerController`. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789854/uiimagepickercontroller-startvideocapture-with-custom-overlay

Comment: @NikosM.:I need to record video with customOverlay. That is play video with the customOverlay..