# Record video on long pressing capture button

Tags: ios

I want to record a video on long pressing capture button. Is there any way out for this? and how to customize the capture button for long press?

TIA

Comment: Hello Surendra.! Do you want long press gestured on UIImagePickerController capture button.?

Comment: Yes. I want to perform different actions for tapping and long pressing.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is not possible in ios.

But if you still want to add than add a custom button/toolbar on that view and perform different action on that controls.

for reference you can use below link and refer a question:-

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789854/uiimagepickercontroller-startvideocapture-with-custom-overlay)

Hope.. This will help you. :)

Comment: If this will help you, than appreciate my answer with upvote/accept it.